# how to automate for checking the connectivity of Azure Data Factory linked services

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created Azure Data Factory with few Linked Services using ARM templates. I want to test the connectivity of linked services using either PowerShell or CLI or any alternative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linked service connectivity test

```
function connect($SubscriptionID)

{

if($null -eq (Get-AzureRMContext).Account)

{

Connect-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $SubscriptionID

}

}

function getBearer([string]$TenantID, [string]$ClientID, [string]$ClientSecret)

{

$TokenEndpoint = {https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $TenantID

$ARMResource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";

$Body = @{

'resource'= $ARMResource

'client_id' = $ClientID

'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'

'client_secret' = $ClientSecret

}

$params = @{

ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}

Body = $Body

Method = 'Post'

URI = $TokenEndpoint

}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

Return "Bearer " + ($token.access_token).ToString()

}

function getLinkedService([string]$LinkedService)

{

$ADFEndpoint = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$DataFactoryName/linkedservices/$($LinkedService)?api-version=2018-06-01"

$params = @{

ContentType = 'application/json'

Headers = @{'accept'='application/json';'Authorization'=$BearerToken}

Method = 'GET'

URI = $ADFEndpoint

}

$a = Invoke-RestMethod @params

Return ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @{"linkedService" = $a} -Depth 10

}

function testLinkedServiceConnection($Body)

{

$AzureEndpoint = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionID/resourcegroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$DataFactoryName/testConnectivity?api-version=2017-09-01-preview"

$params = @{

ContentType = 'application/json'

Headers = @{'accept'='application/json';'Authorization'=$BearerToken}

Body = $Body

Method = 'Post'

URI = $AzureEndpoint

}

Return (Invoke-RestMethod @params).succeeded

}

# These are dummy secrets!

$ClientID = "d8e4efe0-f335-4da8-9adb-38942dca3783"

$ClientSecret = "TNALx46f08RIMui8iUvTCFbbWb/yIS+AQA1WlwBN7oo="

$DataFactoryName = "dataThirstADFv2Test1"

$ResourceGroup = "dataThirstTestBed8"

$SubscriptionID = "d4c56897-10e7-4c62-a139-326bcf267f68"

connect $SubscriptionID

$BearerToken = getBearer "bb0280d2-a9cf-46e8-9485-19d65b1b2c84" $ClientID $ClientSecret

$LinkedServiceBody = getLinkedService "LS_DataThirst_TestBed8_ADLS"

testLinkedServiceConnection $LinkedServiceBody
```

for further reference you can go through [Testing linked services](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/9/23/adfv2-testing-linked-services)
for code [Github link](https://gist.github.com/simondmorias/e4d9e7265a20af8d7d17b92d483e3889)